# Two different SAP hybris version instances on the same machine

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Can I run two different SAP hybris version instances (i.e. 6.1 and 6.4) on the same machine (not simultaneously)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There shouldn't be a problem with that. Hybris licensing works on a Database level. If you plan to use both version on the same database, this might cause a problem because the data schemes are possibly different. The rest is just a matter of tomcat configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can run multiple hybris version even when simultaneously is not required (provided you want to run it on different db). Same can be run simultaneously as well by updating properties

```
tomcat.http.port=
tomcat.ssl.port=
```